# How to input data into an array from an Independant function

Tags: c++, arrays, function

I am currently working on a project. I need write a program that computes the perimeter and volume of 3 boxes. The height, width and depth of the boxes are 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90. The first 3 elements represent the height, width and depth of the first box, respectively speaking. The second group of three represent the second box and the last three represent the last box (height, width, depth).

Now I need to put the 9 given values in array, which I have done. Then i need to use 2 independent functions to calculate the volume and perimeter and I need to use a loop to repeat the calculations for all 3 boxes. once the functions calculate the perimeter and volume, the 6 values (3 perimeters and 3 volumes) need to be placed in array, then displayed.

I initialized an Array and stored the 9 values in the code. I created two independant functions that will compute the perimeter and the volume. I used a loop so so that the perimeter and the volume will be computed for all three boxes. Now I am having trouble figuring out how to store the computed values into an array?

Here is my code:

```
    #include<iostream>

    using namespace std;

    struct myArrayWrapper
    {
        int m_array[9];//Array for the 9 given values
        int n_array[6];//Array for the 6 values we will be computing

    };

    int perimeter(myArrayWrapper a)//function to calculate the perimiter
    {
        int p;
        int* A = a.m_array; 
        int* B = a.n_array;
        for(int b = 0 && int a = 1 && int s = 0; a < 8 && b < 9; a+=3 && b+=3 && s+=2) {//for loop to calculate the perimeter of the 3 boxes
        p = 2*A[a] + 2*A[b];
    }

    }

    int volume(myArrayWrapper a)// function to calculate the volume
    {
    int v;
    int* B = a.m_array;//pointer
    for(int c = 0 && int d = 3 && int e = 6; c < 3; c+=3 && d+=3 && e+=3){
        int v;
        v = B[c]*B[d]*B[e];

    }

    }


    int main()
    {
    myArrayWrapper obj;
    obj.m_array[0] = 10;//height of box 1
    obj.m_array[1] = 40;//height of box 2
    obj.m_array[2] = 70;//height of box 3
    obj.m_array[3] = 20;//width of box 1
    obj.m_array[4] = 50;//width of box 2 
    obj.m_array[5] = 80;//width of box 3
    obj.m_array[6] = 30;//depth of box 1
    obj.m_array[7] = 60;//depth of box 2
    obj.m_array[8] = 90;//depth of box 3

    for(int x = 0; x < 8; x++){//Loop that checks to make sure that the given dimensions are greater than 0
    if(obj.m_array[x]>0)
        cout << "Element number " << x << "is greater than 0" << endl;
    else
        cout << "The element is not greater than 0" << endl;
    return 0;
    }

    perimeter(obj);
    volume(obj);

    }
```

Comment: Do you mean storing the computed values (3 values of perimeter and 3 of volume)in `n_array` ? Besides, why there's no return value in your functions?

Comment: Why don't you use c++ class instead of this struct ?

Comment: Yes, I planned on storing the computed values in n_array. And the functions are not complete since I did know how to store the values. And looking at the code now, using a class would have made it a little easier. If I can't figure out how to make the code work I will definitely try using a class. thanks for the replies.

Answer (score 0):

What it sounds like you need to use is the return statement. This will allow your functions to actually return the value that they are calculating, so your perimeter function would look more like this:

```
int perimeter(myArrayWrapper a)//function to calculate the perimiter
{
    int p;
    /* your code */
    p = 2*A[a] + 2*A[b];
    return p;
}
```

This will return the integer value calculated for p, then in your main loop you can assigne the returned value to your wanted location in your array.

There is more information on the return statement [here.](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/functions/)

One other thing that may give you trouble that I noticed was that your return statement in your main function is going to be called on the first iteration of your for loop. When a return statement is called within a function, the function will actually stop running there and return that value, meaning your main function is stopping before it actually reaches the calls to your perimeter and volume functions.